# Panel animation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, animation, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to perform a slide in/out animation on my windows phone project.
The effect I'm trying to create is that a user presses a button, that a list of buttons ( a panel ) slides in from the side and the current page slides a bit off screen.

Look at a good [example here](http://sport.be.msn.com/app/images/screens/screenshot_i2.jpg) ( the panel is fully slided in, so a small part of the active page is still visible )

Now I think the animations are not that difficult ( but any tips on how to create it are welcome ), but I was wondering how do you add the subtle shadow effect?
If you look at the image you will notice that it's like the panel is underneath the active screen, because of the shadow...

Answer (score 0):

I might have an idea.

-Create a timer, for each tick you execute this:

`int x = pnl.Location.X;
 int y = pnl.Location.Y;
 pnl.Location = new Point(x + 1, y);`

-Then you should create an `if` to stop the timer when the panel is on the right position, for example:

`if (x == 20)
{
tmrMove.Stop();
}`